# SharePoint PowerAutomate Create plain CSV file from email

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I have a simple two stage flow (below) that I am using. It triggers on a email with a file attachment (which is in CSV format) and then saves it to a SharePoint Document folder. All works well except that it is also putting the mime headers at the top of the CSV file. How can I stop it from doing that. See screen shot of output and of flow: ( For File Content I am using Attachments Content)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

YSG,

Can you add a condition to check if the attachment is actually a .csv file? At the moment it looks like it is concatenating a couple of attachments into one file.

Try a setup like below:
*The Condition action checks if the Attachment Name property ends with .csv*

[image]

Comment: I did the test send. It is one csv file. Attachments are multipart mimes.

Comment: Have you tested it with a different e-mail with a different csv file? Does it behave the same way? In this instance you might be able to skip the first 27 rows with a skip function. But that would be a workaround for this instance.